# What would be an appropriate opposite of "advance" in this sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I want to convey the ability to navigate up and down a list of features<sup>*</sup>, similarly to the "next" and "previous" scene buttons in a DVD.

What would be the appropriate opposite of *advance* in "advance to the next feature"? Is "revert to the previous feature" the appropriate phrase?

<sub>* Feature in this case refers to a GIS feature (record), though this is irrelevant for the question.</sub>

Comment: In the context of on-screen menu choices, normally the function would simply be labelled *"Back"*, but for the more general case, *"Go back"* would be better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a sentence, I would suggest *[return](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/return)* or *go back*:

> Return to the previous feature.
>
> Go back to the previous feature.

*[Revert](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revert) to* means *change back to*, not *go back to*.

If you're using buttons, you could consider being more concise, and have them say *Next* and *Previous*, or *Forward* and *Back*.

Comment: I agree; _revert_ would be probably understood similarly to "revert the last changes."

Answer (score 3):

The literal opposite of “advance” would be “retreat” or possibly “withdraw”.

If you don't want to use the commonly understood “Next” and “Previous”, I would actually suggest *not* using advance, but rather phrases tailored to your application domain that will be best understood by your particular specialized users.

“Forward” and “Back” may be more suitable as single-word labels.

Comment: I completely agree with your logic. However, 'advance' is a verb and your suggested alternatives are not.

Answer (score 2):

***Advance*** is a relic the magtape era: Advance (tape)/ Rewind (tape).

In the current paradigm, the equivalent terms would probably be 'forward'/'back(ward)', 'next'/'previous', etc.

Give me **<**  **>** any day.

Answer (score 1):

You may say *back* or *move back*.